# PySparkDataframe column header concat based on non zero values

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

```
+------+-----+------+-------------------+--------------------+----------+
|Manfr|  prodid|region|         absprice33|        absprice27|absprice29|
+-----+-----  +------+-------------------+------------------ +----------+
|  abc|   47   |    US|-0.6015412046017017|1.2074692228904986| 0        |
+------+-----  +------+-------------------+------------------+----------+
|  bcd|   47   |    US|-0.6015412046017017| 0                |1.204986  |
+------+-----  +------+-------------------+------------------+----------+
```

above is the input i want output like below

```
Manfr|  prodid|region| new_col
  abc|   47   |    US| absprice33, absprice27
  bcd|   47   |    US| absprice33, absprice29
```

I want to contact the column names, if the values are not equal to 0. Please note rows are unique/no dups for Manfr|  prodid|region combination.

Can you help using pyspark dataframe

Comment: vars = ['abs1', 'abs2'] # dynamic columns
aggList = [func.when(func.col(colname) !=0 , func.concat_ws('-',colname))  for colname in vars]
DF = DF.withColumn("new_col", *aggList )                                                                            "TypeError: withColumn() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given"     I can try with pands which i dont want, is there any way i can achieve in pyspark dataframe